# How may I popup a MsgBox error when the user tries to perform an action (for example delete)?

Tags: excel, vba

I've code with a delete button that deletes a row according to the user's choice.

I want to restrict the user from deleting a specific row or Range (equivalent to the line).

```vb
Private Sub Deletar_Click()
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult, tbl As ListObject, error As VbMsgBoxResult
    answer = MsgBox("You want to proceed with the delete?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Excluir Linha"):
    If answer = vbYes & Range.Row(2).Select Then 
       error = Msgbox("You cant delete this row",vbCritical+vbRetryCancel,"Error")
    If answer <> vbYes Then Exit Sub 
     
    Set tbl = MySheet.ListObjects("DataTable")
    tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(Range.Row - tbl.DataBodyRange.Row).Delete
End Sub
```

I end up getting the following error:

Wrong number or arguments or...
[image]

Comment: `If answer = vbYes and Selection.Row = 2 Then`

Comment: If you already know Row2 can't be deleted then it would be better to just tell the user that - don't first ask them if they want to delete it...

Comment: Thx its(such a rookie mistake) working but now im getting error 91 about the last line of code. but at least i think that answers the question

Comment: @TimWilliams I agree with u but in that scenario "he" should be able to delete the other lines. Then i should just add a 'Then Exit Sub' after the first if statement. . Im trying to simulate a scenario where ive no contact with the user to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: split out the logic for figuring out what listobject row is selected.

Maybe like this:

```vb
Sub Deletar_Click()
    Dim rw As ListRow
    
    Set rw = SelectedListRow(Selection, mySheet.ListObjects("DataTable"))
    
    If rw Is Nothing Then     'make sure a row in the data table has been selected
        MsgBox "First select one or more cells in the data row to be deleted"
    ElseIf rw.Index = 1 Then  'first row can't be deleted
        MsgBox "The first row cannot be deleted", vbExclamation
    Else
        'OK to deelte on user confirmation
        If MsgBox("Delete selected row?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Excluir Linha") = vbYes Then
            rw.Delete
        End If
    End If
End Sub

'Given a Range and a ListObject, return a ListRow corresponding to `rng` (or Nothing
'   if rng is noth within the listobject's DatabodyRange
Function SelectedListRow(rng As Range, tbl As ListObject) As ListRow
    Dim sel As Range, rowIndex As Long
    If Not rng.Parent Is tbl.Parent Then Exit Function 'on different sheets...
    Set sel = Application.Intersect(rng.Cells(1), tbl.DataBodyRange) 'only check top-left cell of `rng`
    If Not sel Is Nothing Then
        rowIndex = 1 + (sel.Row - tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(1).Row) 'which table row is selected?
        Set SelectedListRow = tbl.ListRows(rowIndex)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: im getting the error ' Subscript out of range - error 9' in the line  'tbl.ListRows(rowIndex).Delete' when i try to delete the other lines . Maybe i should post the remaining of the code so i u'll be able to aid me better?

Comment: Sorry - basic math error: should be `rowIndex = 1 + (sel.Row - tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(1).Row)`